# Critical Error: [0100] - Unable to connect or authenticate to the Sentora database (sentora_core)

Tags: mysql, database

"Critical Error: [0100] - Unable to connect or authenticate to the Sentora database (sentora_core).

### We advice that you contact the server administrator to ensure that the database server is online and that the correct connection parameters are being used."

How Can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

login to SSH

type sudo bash

Then type/copy paste

systemctl start mariadb.service

error establishing database will be solved instantly.